# Is this sequence of functions (involving antiderivative and truncations) uniformly convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity, uniform-convergence

Define for $m \in (0,1)$ fixed the sequence
$$f_n(x) := \int_0^x |T_n\left((|y|-\frac{1}{n})^+ + \frac{1}{n}\right)\text{sign}(y)|^{m-1}$$ where we define $T_n(y) =y$ if $|y| \leq n$ and otherwise $T_n(y) = n$.

Does $f_n$ converge uniformly to $f(x) := \frac{1}{m}x|x|^{m-1}$? These functions are defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

I think it is enough to show that the integrand is uniformly convergent as a sequence, but I got no idea how to start.

Answer (score 1):

Just use dominated convergence. $T_n(y)=y$ for $n\geq x$ and $y\in[0,x]$. You have $|(|y|-1/n)^++1/n|\leq |y|.$  Equivalently, you have the uniform convergence you desire because for $|y|<1/n$, your error is no more than $1/n$ and you have exact equality when $|y|>1/n$.

But is your question written correctly? There's a bunch of unnecessary issues in it, like $\mbox{sgn}(y)$ which has an absolute value around it.

Comment: Thanks, will think about your answer. The formula is correct, I think the sign is the only unnecessary bit.

Comment: So I think your first paragraph, you show that the integrand is uniformly bounded in $k$ by integralbe functions, so that the DCT can be applied. But how does the DCT give uniform convergences of the $f_n$?

Comment: @ewl: I thought maybe you were trying to evaluate the integral. The sentence after dct says why convergence is uniform.

Comment: Please can you expand on this? I'm not getting it.

Comment: Just like stated: split into two cases: $|y|>1/n$ and $|y|\leq 1/n$. In the former there is no error, in the latter the error is $1/n$.

Comment: Aren't you assuming $m-1 > 0$ here?